# Passing through a 2d binary array recursively and counting the number of "1's" to pass through

Tags: python, maze

I'm attempting to learn programming and one concept I'm really struggling to understand is recursion.

Edit: Below is a link to an image of the actual question which explains the instructions a lot better. I think my explanation wasn't the best.

[Instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZNBX.png)

I'm trying to write a program using recursion on python that takes a 2 dimensional binary array of A[0,...,n-1][0,...,n-1] and returns the minimum number of "1's" that must be passed through to reach the end point. The start point is A[0][0] and the end point is A[n-1][n-1]. You can only move one cell at a time, by either moving one cell to the right or one cell down. The array contains only 0's and 1's. It is similar to a maze where one must pass through the 0's, and the 1's act as a wall but here one can and will likely need to travel through a few 1's. The output will be the minimum number of 1's required to pass through to reach the end point.

I'm not sure if this is the right approach. I think I may be better off with the 1 function. I also can't seem to figure out how to count the number of dangerous zones that must be passed through. I think you may notice that I am new to this and I would be grateful if someone could lead me in the right direction.

```
def minCellsTravel(grid):

    gridWidth = len(grid[0])
    gridHeight = len(grid)

    def helperFn(row, col):

            # if we already reached the rightmost end
            if row == gridHeight-1 and col == gridWidth-1:
                    return grid[row][col]

            start = grid[row][col]
            downMove = None
            if row < gridHeight - 1:
                    downMove = start + helperFn(row + 1, col)

            rightMove = None
            if col < gridWidth - 1:
                    rightMove = start + helperFn(row, col + 1)

            if rightMove and downMove:
                    return min(rightMove, downMove)
            elif rightMove:
                    return rightMove
            else:
                    return downMove
```

Comment: I would suggest that you explain better, even to yourself, how your algorithm will work.  Then explain it here.  There's nothing in your code that I can see that explains what your code will really do.  For example, your setting `minNum` to 1, but then never making it any bigger.  I think you need to pass `minNum` to your function at each level of recursion, have your function add to that number, and the return its new value.  And why are you testing [0][0] as a special case?  You'll do that at every level of recursion.  Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```py
def solve(row, col, A):

    if (row == A.shape[0] - 1) and (col == A.shape[1] - 1):
        return A[row][col]
    if (row >= A.shape[0]) or (col >= A.shape[1]):
        return A.shape[0] + A.shape[1]

    left = solve(row + 1, col, A)
    right = solve(row, col + 1, A)
    best_path = min(right, left)

    return best_path + A[row][col]
```

The idea is that at each cell you can either go right or down, and the best solution starting on this cell is the best solution starting on the cell to your right or the best solution starting on the cell to your left. Take the best one plus the value of the current cell and you have the solution starting on the current cell.

Although is possible to solve this problem with recursion, dynamic programming is more efficient is this kind of problems, take a look at it if you're curious.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation. It helps a lot but how about when the only way through is a "1" or a "dangerous zone"? I think I may not have properly explained the instructions. I've posted an image that better explains it

Comment: There is no problem if the only way through is a "1", what really matters is the minimum cost you can get if you go by the right cell and the bottom cell. For example, if the bottom cell is a "1" and the right cell is a "0" that doesn't mean that the right cell is a better path, because it is possible that what comes after the "0" are only "1"s. You don't have to worry about passing through a "1" or not, the recursion will solve that for you when it tells the best path starting from each neighbor cell.

Comment: Oh right, thanks a lot. Do you know how one would get it to count the minimum number of "1"s that need to be passed through? Would a simple "if A[row][col] == 1:"
"numOfOnes += 1" before the return function do it?

Comment: The answer I provided do exactly that. Given that you marked it as correct I'm supposing you understood why, but if you have any doubts let me know

Comment: Oh, you're right. Hmm I don't understand why exactly but I'll go through it step by step on pythontutor to try and understand it. Thank you